# Preserve data in SQLITE when adding new Columns

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I have an app currently Live and in app I use a sqlite table to store game highscore. Then when i needed to add shuffle feature, i added a Column in table by first checking if Column exists.

**Current Code**

```
local function setupDatabase()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)

    local playerSetup = [[
        CREATE TABLE playerInfo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, highscore);
        INSERT INTO playerInfo VALUES(NULL, '0');
    ]]
    db:exec(playerSetup)

    if not dbColumnExists( db, "playerInfo", "shuffles") then
        local sql = "alter table playerInfo add column shuffles"
        db:exec(sql)
        db:close()
        M.shuffles = 3  -- Set to default
        M.savePlayerInfo()
    else
        db:close()
    end
end
setupDatabase()
```

Now I want to add a Save Score feature and this is my new code:

```
local function setupDatabase()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)

    local playerSetup = [[
        CREATE TABLE playerInfo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, highscore);
        INSERT INTO playerInfo VALUES(NULL, '0');
    ]]
    db:exec(playerSetup)

    if not dbColumnExists( db, "playerInfo", "shuffles") then
        local sql = "alter table playerInfo add column shuffles"
        db:exec(sql)
        --db:close()
        M.shuffles = 3  -- Set to default
        M.savePlayerInfo()
    end
    if not dbColumnExists( db, "playerInfo", "startscore") then
        local sql = "alter table playerInfo add column startscore"
        db:exec(sql)
        M.savePlayerInfo()
        M.saveScore()
    end
    if not dbColumnExists( db, "playerInfo", "savecount") then
        local sql = "alter table playerInfo add column savecount"
        db:exec(sql)
        M.savecount = 3
        M.savePlayerInfo()
    end
    db:close()
end
setupDatabase()
```

**Issue faced:**

The issue I am facing now is when someone installs the LIVE app and buys shuffles, lets say 10 credits for shuffle, and then installs the new update, the 10 credits for shuffle gets wipped out.

Is there a better way to ensure I preserve existing shuffle credits in database?

Thanks

**Loading And Saving Data**

```
M.loadPlayerInfo = function()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM playerInfo WHERE id = 1") do
        M.highscore = tonumber(row.highscore)
        M.shuffles = tonumber(row.shuffles)
        M.startscore = tonumber(row.startscore)
        M.savecount = tonumber(row.savecount)
    end
    db:close()
end

M.savePlayerInfo = function()
    local dbPath = system.pathForFile("appInfo.db3", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local db = sqlite3.open(dbPath)
    local update = "UPDATE playerInfo SET highscore='" .. M.highscore .."', shuffles='" .. M.shuffles .. "', savecount='" .. M.savecount .. "' WHERE id=1"
    db:exec(update)
    db:close()
end
```

Comment: It isn't clear what "shuffle credits" are or how they are stored in your database.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In app, when you purchase a shuffle, it adds it into the DB. This credit is used during game play. In code I have a savefunction that is called to update the table.

Comment: Well, are you loading the existing row into `M` ?

Comment: just added the bits that loads and save data. thanks

Comment: Well I had to look for alternative solution to this by using a json file to store the needed data and avoiding the DB. All works fine now for me.

Still happy for someone to solve this as it might come in handy in future.